# Does every bicategory have a "delaxing object"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

If I'm not mistaken, there is a bicategory $\mathsf{Monad}$ given as follows:

1. Start with the associative operad.
2. Deloop it to obtain a multicategory.
3. Adjoin objects and morphisms as necessary to obtain a monoidal category.
4. Deloop *that* to obtain a bicategory.

So basically, $\mathsf{Monad}$ is the "double-delooping" of the associative operad.

I think that $\mathsf{Monad}$ has the following special property: given a bicategory $\mathfrak{B}$, a monad in $\mathfrak{B}$ is the same thing as a functor $\mathsf{Monad} \rightarrow \mathfrak{B}$. Now recall that lax functors $1 \rightarrow \mathfrak{B}$ are the "same as" monads in $\mathfrak{B}$. If so, then it would seem that lax functors out of $1$ are the same as ordinary functors out of $\mathsf{Monad}$. We might call $\mathsf{Monad}$ the "delaxing object" of $1$.

> **Question.** Have I made any mistakes above? If not, is it true that every bicategory $\mathfrak{A}$ has a "delaxing object" $\mathfrak{A}'$ such that lax functors out of $\mathfrak{A}$ are the "same as" ordinary functors out of $\mathfrak{A}'$? If not, is there a way to repair this problem, say by working instead with $(\infty,\infty)$-categories instead of bicategories, or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the theory of lax functors of $(\infty,\infty)$-categories is not sufficiently developed to answer that version of your question.  But for your main question, yes.

Given a bicategory $\mathfrak A$, you certainly have a set of objects and for each pair of objects $a,b\in\mathfrak A$ a category $\mathfrak A(a,b)$.  Define a new category $\mathfrak A''$ as the free category with the same objects as in $\mathfrak A$ and generated by the categories $\mathfrak A(a,b)$.  So for instance a 1-morphism in $\mathfrak A''$ is a composable sequence of $1$-morphisms in $\mathfrak A$.  Now given a 1-morphism in $\mathfrak A$, there's a corresponding "generating" 1-morphism in $\mathfrak A''$, and on the other hand given a 1-morphism in $\mathfrak A''$, think of it as a sequence in $\mathfrak A$, and compose, and get a 1-morphism in $\mathfrak A$.  Combining these, you find that for every 1-morphism $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$ in $\mathfrak A''$ there's a corresponding generating 1-morphism $f_1f_2\dots f_n$ in $\mathfrak A''$. (Choose some way of parenthesizing the composition.  The choice won't matter because of later imposition of naturality conditions.)  This assignment is functorial for the 2-morphisms.  Let's now add to $\mathfrak A''$ some new 2-morphisms $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n) \Rightarrow f_1f_2\cdots f_n$.  Now I want to impose some relations on these new 2-morphisms (and the old ones).  First, I'd like them to be "natural" in a sense that I won't unpack, but the idea is that the 2-morphism $(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n) \Rightarrow f_1f_2\cdots f_n$ depends naturally on the choice of $f_1,\dots,f_n$.

Second, and more importantly, I want that compositions of these new morphisms should agree.  Really what I mean is the following.  Suppose that you have some monotonic function $\phi:\{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,m\}$.  Then for each $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$, $\phi^{-1}(i)$ is an interval $\{j,j+1,\dots,j+k\}$.  So given a length-$n$ 1-morphism $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ in $A''$, it makes sense to compose $f_j\dots f_{j+k}$; as $i$ varies, you get a length-$m$ 1-morphism $(f_1f_2\cdots f_{k_1},f_{k_1+1}f_{k_1+2}\cdots f_{k_2},\dots,f_{k_m}\cdots f_n)$ in $A''$.  (What I described earlier is the $m=1$ case.  If $\phi^{-1}(i) = \emptyset$, the composition is the appropriate identity map.)  What I really want to do is to adjoint to $\mathfrak A''$ a 2-morphism $(f_1,\dots,f_n) \Rightarrow (f_1f_2\cdots f_{k_1},f_{k_1+1}f_{k_1+2}\cdots f_{k_2},\dots,f_{k_m}\cdots f_n)$ for each 1-morphism $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ in $\mathfrak A''$ and each monotonic function $\phi : \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,m\}$.  I demand that these new 2-morphisms be natural for the 2-morphisms I already had, and that moreover the 2-morphism be functorial in $\phi$ in the sense that compositions of monotonic functions correspond to compositions of 2-morphisms (and identity monotonic functions correspond to identity 2-morphisms).

Let me call the resulting bicategory, generated by the 1- and 2-morphisms as above and with the given relations between 2-morphisms, $\mathfrak A'$.  If I am not mistaken, ("pseudo") functors $\mathfrak A' \to \mathfrak B$ are the same as lax functors $\mathfrak A \to \mathfrak B$.

Answer (score 8):

Theo's answer gives a very explicit construction; I just wanted to mention that there is an abstract framework for it as well.  For any 2-monad $T$, there are notions of strict, pseudo, and lax (and colax) morphisms between $T$-algebras, and if $T$ is well-behaved then the inclusions of the 2-category of strict maps into the other three 2-categories have left adjoints.  Bicategories are in fact the algebras of a 2-monad $T$ on the 2-category of "Cat-enriched graphs", and the four kinds of $T$-morphism are the four kinds of functor between bicategories.  (The $T$-2-cells are not the usual sort of pseudonatural transformations, though; they are called [icons](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/icon).)  Thus, the left adjoint in the lax case (sometimes called the "lax morphism classifier") is what you are looking for.  (By definition it gives you that lax morphisms out of $A$ are the same as *strict* morphisms out of $A'$, but it so happens that $A'$ is always what's called "flexible", so that every pseudo morphism out of it is equivalent to a strict one.)  If you unravel the abstract construction of $A'$ as a "codescent object", you'll get Theo's version.

References:

- Blackwell, Kelly, and Power: *Two-dimensional monad theory*
- Lack, *Codescent objects and coherence* and *A 2-categories companion*

(By the way, the monoidal category that you delooped to get Monad is the [augmented simplex category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category).)